# display data from datatable to inputText in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i m having a difficult time trying to figure out how to display data from datatable to an input text when row selected here is my jsf page code :

i know that there is a litle detail missing in my code but i don't know where .

can you please help me ??

and thank you !

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>


        <h:form>
            <h1><center><h:outputText value="List des Op"/></center></h1>
            <p:dataTable value="#{opController.op}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{opController.setSelected(selected)}" var="item" rowKey="#{item.opPK}"  >

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OpNSeq"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.opPK.opNSeq}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OpNum"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.opNum}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OpDate"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.opDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OpVisa"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.opVisa}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
            <h3><center><h:outputText value="Information sur OP"/></center></h3>

            <p:outputLabel value="N° Op"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{opController.selected.opNum}" readonly="true" />

        </h:form>
    </f:view>

</h:body>
```

Comment: You don't do anything anywhere regarding selection, updating etc... Did you have a look at all at the PrimeFaces showcase regarding [datatable and selection](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an ID to your ipnutText and use Ajax to update It when you select an element :
add this ajax event inside datatable tag

```
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="myInput">
```

and update your InputText

```
        <p:inputText id="myInput" value="#{opController.selected.opNum}" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: thank you  BENKHALFA Mohammed Amine , you have resolved my issue :D

Comment: You are welcome ! please don't forget to vote and mark this as resolved

Comment: now I m getting this error     For input string: "opPK"    in the rowKey field   do you  know how to solve it ??

Comment: @OthmaneRamzi please Develop your question so that we can help you

Comment: there is no need, i solved this issue , it was a sql query error thnk you anyway for your help